# ios push notifications to a specific view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

My app receives remote push notifications and upon receiving them, i would like to take it to a specific view controller(pretty much all the time). I have seen code like this (on didReceiveRemoteNotification). I am using storyboard for my apps.

```
    UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;
    PushViewController *pvc = [vc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someid"];
    [vc presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This seems straightforward enough. But will it have any impact on memory allocation, as it looks like every time a push notification arrives, we are instantiating a new view controller. Is this the best practice?

Comment: why are you allocating the rootview to vc ?cant you use self.storyboard ?

Comment: This is just an example that i have seen online...do you have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like:

```
    PushViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someid"];

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You dont need to allocate uiviewcontroller as rootview everytime unless you want to have a uiviewcontroller present your pushVC.

if you are doing this in app delegate, the get the storyboard reference by:

```
  UIStoryboard *test=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"name" bundle:nil];
```

and then call

```
  [test instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier.....
```

Comment: Mr T, we are still instantiating  the new view controller everytime a push happens?

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will try this one out.

Answer (score 0):

The above code you have mentioned is fine. But the logic remains upto you on how to handle. If it is intended that you always want different VC's for your push notification, then it is fine.

Say if you get two push notification instantly where two VC's will be presented immediately. But you want just one screen for the Push then this will be in trouble.

If you want to have one pushViewController object then you can make it a global object and do a simple check like this

```
UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController;
if(!pvc)
{
   pvc = [vc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someid"];
}
[vc updatePushViewControllerDependingOnPushNotificationObject:somePushObject];
[vc presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```